# Cambiar la opacidad y estilos de diferentes divs cuando paso el raton por encima

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo que quiero hacer es cuando pase el ratón por encima de el `div` con clase "pilot tetsuta" pase a estar como *background* (es decir, jugar con el `opacity` como digo en el título), y pase a ser visible el `div` con clase "about-tetsuta" ocupando todo el div "pilot tetsuta" (solo quedando visible la imagen que tengo como background del div pilot tetsuta). En cambio los `div`s con clase "container-name" y "container-stats" pasarían a no ser visibles.

El código que he hecho para intentar hacerlo es éste:

```css
.pilot.tetsuta{
 background-image: url('https://cloud.modyocdn.com/uploads/c8d5a62d-7b6e-4a70-a1e8-348c7044a3a2/original/tetsutav2.jpg');
 color: #FFF;
 position: relative;
}
.pilot.tetsuta:hover > .container-name,
.pilot.tetsuta:hover > .container-stats {
 opacity: 0.9;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
 -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
 -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
 -ms-transition: opacity 500ms;
 transition: opacity 500ms;
 color: #834c4c;
}

.pilot.tetsuta:hover > .about-tetsuta {
 opacity:1;
}

.about-tetsuta {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 opacity:0;
 z-index:2;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
 -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
 -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
 -ms-transition: opacity 500ms;
 transition: opacity 500ms;
 margin: 10px;
}

.about-tetsuta .name{
 font-family: 'Montserrat-Black';
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 36px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class=" pilot tetsuta">
<div class="about-tetsuta">
 <span class="name">Tetsuta Nagashima</span>
 <br>
 <span class="about">
 Habitual del campeonato japonés, Nagashima fue segundo en la categoría J-GP3 en 2012, sexto en la J-GP2 en 2013 a los mandos de una TSR y  vigésimo en el debut mundialista en el Gran Premio de       Japón, dentro del equipo JiR. En 2014 disputaba 12 Grandes Premios y en 2016 participaba en dos rondas en condición de wildcard y conseguía sus primeros puntos en el campeonato aparte de          participar en el FIM CEV Repsol donde conseguía el subcampeonato. En 2017 forma parte del Teluru SAG Team.
 </span>
</div>
<div class="container-name">
  <span class="name">Tetsuta Nagashima</span>
  <br>
  <span class="info">Kanagawa, Japón | 02/07/92 | 175cm | 61kg</span>
</div>
<div class="container-stats tetsuta">
 <div class="stat">
  <img src="https://cloud.modyocdn.com/uploads/8f9cd150-1aaf-4dad-8456-810ff6700aa4/original/podium_icono_blanc.png"/>
  <br><br>
  <span id="podium-tetsuta">0</span> Podios
 </div>
 <div class="stat">
  <img src="https://cloud.modyocdn.com/uploads/7d47e82b-aea2-4843-a021-2841a77056c9/original/tiempo_icono_blanco.png"/>
  <br><br>
  <span id="lap-tetsuta">0</span> Vueltas rápidas
 </div>
 <div class="stat">
  <img src="https://cloud.modyocdn.com/uploads/c7654ce4-acba-4581-9e85-4801385f80cb/original/GP_icono_blanco.png"/>
  <br><br>
  <span id="gp-tetsuta">27</span> GP Disputados
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ahora mismo paso el ratón por encima y el `opacity` 0.9 se aplica en todo el `div`  con clase "pilot tetsuta", me gustaría que tanto el `div` con clase "container-name" como el de "status", se quedaran NO visibles para el usuario.

Después de eso habría que hacer que el `div` "about-tetsuta" ocupara todo el `div` "pilot-tetsuta" ya que no me lo ocupa (una solución rápida seria ponerle un `padding`) pero entonces tendría que utilizar `media query` para los diferentes tamaños.

Como se ve sin hover:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como quiero que se vea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve cuando hago hover actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué falla ahora mismo o qué está funcionando?

Comment: Lo ideal sería usar javascript, hay alguna razón por lo que lo necesites con css?

Comment: La verdad es que no, podría hacerlo con JS también.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema de aplicar una opacidad al contenedor padre es que se aplicará a todos los elementos contenidos en él. Es algo tedioso, pero sería mejor aplicar el CSS a los elementos hijos en lugar de al padre.

Entonces lo que habría que hacer sería:

- Ponerle una posición relativa al `div` contenedor (".pilot.tetsuta")
- Cuando se pase el ratón por encima del contendor, esconder "container-name" y "stats" (cambiando su opacidad como le estabas haciendo al padre)
- Ponerle posición absoluta al "about" (ya lo tienes) y que ocupe todo el tamaño del contenedor, esconderlo de primeras y mostrarlo cuando el ratón se pase por encima.

Algo como esto:

```css
.pilot.tetsuta {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* esto antes aplicaba al padre, ahora sólo a ciertos descendientes */

.pilot.tetsuta:hover>.container-name,
.pilot.tetsuta:hover>.container-stats {
  opacity: 0.6;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms;
  -o-transition: all 500ms;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
  color: #834c4c;
}


/* mostramos el about cuando el ratón se ponga encima del padre */

.pilot.tetsuta:hover>.about-tetsuta {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* hacemos que ocupe todo y que esté oculto de primeras con opacity 0 */

.about-tetsuta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -ms-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  margin: 10px;
}

.about-tetsuta .name {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Black';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class=" pilot tetsuta">
  <div class="about-tetsuta">
    <span class="name">Tetsuta Nagashima</span>
    <br>
    <span class="about">
 Habitual del campeonato japonés, Nagashima fue segundo en la categoría J-GP3 en 2012, sexto en la J-GP2 en 2013 a los mandos de una TSR y  vigésimo en el debut mundialista en el Gran Premio de       Japón, dentro del equipo JiR. En 2014 disputaba 12 Grandes Premios y en 2016 participaba en dos rondas en condición de wildcard y conseguía sus primeros puntos en el campeonato aparte de          participar en el FIM CEV Repsol donde conseguía el subcampeonato. En 2017 forma parte del Teluru SAG Team.
 </span>
  </div>
  <div class="container-name">
    <span class="name">Tetsuta Nagashima</span>
    <br>
    <span class="info">Kanagawa, Japón | 02/07/92 | 175cm | 61kg</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container-stats tetsuta">
    <div class="stat">
      <img src="random.png" />
      <br><br>
      <span id="podium-tetsuta">0</span> Podios
    </div>
    <div class="stat">
      <img src="random.png" />
      <br><br>
      <span id="lap-tetsuta">0</span> Vueltas rápidas
    </div>
    <div class="stat">
      <img src="random.png" />
      <br><br>
      <span id="gp-tetsuta">27</span> GP Disputados
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64827/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-alvaro-montoro).

Comment: pregunta editada

Comment: El nuevo problema parece que es algún estilo externo (en concreto un `line-height`) que podría estar afectando ese contenido y por eso se vería tan junto. Deberías inspeccionar tu código (las herramientas del programador se abren con F12) y ver si hay algún estilo que se le esté aplicando de más.

Comment: Ya esta todo, gracias ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar JQuery para realizarlo. Con un solo hover realizas todas las acciones necesarias.

```
//Hover sobre el div general tetsusa
$(".tetsusa").hover(function(){
    //Aplicamos opacidad a cada div segun quieras
    $(".tetsusa").css({opacity:0.5});
    $(".container-name").css({opacity:0.9});
    $(".container-stats").css({opacity:0.9});
});
```

Modifica las opacidades a tu gusto, son valores de ejemplo.

En el archivo css deja los valores como quieres que se muestren por defecto.

Comment: Sabeis si hay alguna manera de subir una foto de como se ve? Tengo el como se ve y como se tiene que ver, y la verdad es que no me acaba de funcionar bien.